# two fork() calls?

Tags: process, system-calls, fork

I know that if I call `fork()` once the parent will receive child_id, while the child will receive 0  and if it is -1 means fail.

My question is if I've two `fork()` calls, how to distinguish between child1 and child2 and parent?

I think like:

```
fork1_id <0 || fork2_id < 0  >> fail
fork2_id==0   >> child2
fork1_id==fork2_id  >> child1 
else  >> parent
```

Comment: I did not vote to close this as "off-topic", since questions about `fork()` are arguably on topic here since it is a *nix thing. However, I did vote to close it as "unclear" (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if I've two fork() calls, how to distinguish between child1 and child2 and parent?

You would need to post actual code, since it is ambiguous what you mean.  If you literally mean this:

```
fork()
fork()
```

Then you have to distinguish between:

```
Parent -> Child1 -> Grandchild
       -> Child2
```

Since after the first fork, the first child will fork a grandchild.

Or, you might have meant the second fork is only in the parent.  In any case, you distinguish the parent and child of the second fork the same way you did the first one.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code ; i need to calls another fork after the first one, then according if_conditions : print  I am the child_1 process  or  I am the child_2 process  or  I am the parent ... hope it's clear now ;

```
int main()
{
pid_t childpid; 

childpid = fork();


    if (childpid == 0) 
    {
        printf("I am the child process!\n");

    }
    else if(childpid > 0) 
    {
        printf("I am the parent process!\n");
    }

else 
{
    perror("fork"); /* display error message */

}
return 0;
}
```